# Python 3.5 - Kivy Android - ScrollableLabel(ScrollView) - Working on a single line of code for two days

Tags: android, android-layout, python-3.x, kivy

```
     #!/usr/local/bin/python
          # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

from kivy.properties import StringProperty

from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
import kivy.input.postproc.doubletap
import random

# Below is the dictionary file, it is over five thousand lines and one million characters, editting it manually may slow the computer down for a moment.
d = {'''massive dictionary''': '''in this format''', '''massive dictionary''': '''in this format'''}

while True:
    i = 1
    random_list = random.sample(d.items(), i )
    print('---------+---------')
    randomList = random_list

    # This prints a less aesthetic version compared to the tuple below.
    #print(randomList)


    #for key, value in random_list: # returns the dictionary as a list of value pairs -- a tuple.
        #print(key, value)



    Builder.load_string('''
<ScrollableLabel>:
    text: 
    Label:
        text: root.text
        font_size: 50
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        **on_touch_down: self.text = "test"**
''')
#on_touch_down: root.children.remove() = randomList()
#on_touch_down: root.remove_widget(self)
#on_touch_up: widget.add_widget(self)
    class ScrollableLabel(ScrollView):
        for key, value in random_list:
            text = key + value
            #text = str(randomList)


    runTouchApp(ScrollableLabel())

    #class InputPostprocDoubleTap():
        #on_press=
        #runTouchApp(InputPostprocDoubleTap())
```

This is where I need help: `on_touch_down: self.text = "test"`

I want to get the key and value from this part: `for key, value in random_list: text = key + value`

and be able to insert them into here: `on_touch_down: self.text = "test"`

*PLEASE BE AWARE
ScrollableLabel(ScrollView) only allows one widget!*

*What does this program do?* This randomly picks a entry from a massive glossary and prints it on the cellphone or tablet screen. The user can scroll through the text or tap to find a new random glossary entry.

TL;DR

YOUTUBE VIDEO EXAMPLE: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdcUg_rX2fM

Answer (score 1):

[ScrollableLabel](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Scrollable-Label) is a ScrollView containing a Label, so you can't add another Label in it, because ScrollView can only have 1 child.

You probably just want to remove the `Label:` line, and unindent everything under it

but you may want a simple ScrollView with a GridLayout containing all the text Labels instead. Although considering the number of options, something smarter like RecycleView (in kivy-garden) is probably what you should use.